# Windows cmd Echo to file from a SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, cmd

I am trying to Echo to a file, in SQL Server, a variable. I am using the Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell function. Already made sure that it is enabled and tested it. It works, but when I have to echo my variable it doesn't work. No exception is thrown. The variable length is about 700 characters, so I don't think that is the problem.

This is my code (@XMLOUTPUT is decalred as NVARCHAR(4000)):

`DECLARE @Cmd AS NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @Cmd = 'echo ' +  @XMLOUTPUT + ' > C:\temp\TestOutputXML.txt'
EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @Cmd`

I am thinking it might be some characters in the variable itself (it is an XML, so maybe some new line or some "<" , ">") but I can't find any "rule" as to what is fine and what causes problems. Can you help me?

**PS:** I know that printing to a file directly from SQL Server is not good practice, but this is what I have to do.

Comment: @XMLOUTPUT is NULL may be?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? If you want to export data, use the appropriate tools like SSIS. You don't need and shouldn't use `xp_cmd` as it requires relaxing security and will execute the command with elevated priviledges.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Why don't you use SSIS to export the data? Or use `sqlcmd` from the command line, or `bcp` with XML formatting?

Comment: @IvanStarostin it is not, I have a check before in the code.

Comment: An 700 character XML file is definitely not going to work with `ECHO`. Definitely `>` is a specific operator in DOS. What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What I am trying to do is simply export an NVARCHAR to a txt file whenever I call a Stored Procedure. I will take a look at SSIS and bcp and see if it can help me.

Comment: @Axel2D you just repeated the title, you didn't explain what you want to do at all. *Why* are you trying to export that nvarchar? What does it contain? Query results? That's "exporting data". There are a lot of tools for that. It's *not* something you run from inside the database and definitely not something you do with `xp_cmd` and `echo`

Comment: @Axel2D, I think your NVARCHAR is more than 4000 character. See the limit for the [length parameters passed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think that what I want to do is pretty clear. The file contains an XML formatted text. I get it, there are some better tools for this task and I am currently looking at them. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Axel2D no it isn't, you still repeat the title. Where did that thing come from? A query, a field? That's still data export. Explain what you're really trying to do, not how you think it's done.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have a table, I want to extract data from it and format it to XML, than save it to a file. Does this help?

Comment: @Axel2D which means you don't have any files or variables. You just want to export the results as XML. Which can be done with SSIS, bcp, sqlcmd, powershell. Read [8 Ways to Export SQL Results To a Text File](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Export/147145/) for a list of possible techniques. You can generate XML from query results with the `FOR XML` clause. All of those techniques can write the output to a target file.

Comment: @Axel2D it also means this question is too broad - it requires an entire article just to list the available techniques. If you want a specific question in the form of "Use this technique and write your query that way" you'll have to explain how you want to export the data (periodically? run by the DBA? after a user request?), where you want to write the data (locally, a remote folder?), if there are any restrictions, eg running on a hosted machine without SQL Server Agent?